# Thin Web Server - X-Frame-Options configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

I have a ruby app running on my Linux VPS.

```
http://192.155.83.120:5000/
```

I believe that its web interface runs of Thin Web Server. It says in the Response Headers in Chrome's Inspector...

```
Server:thin 1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso
```

The issue I'm having is that it generates this in the HTTP headers...

```
X-Frame-Options:sameorigin
```

I'd like to call this webpage into an iframe on another website - but this won't let me. I don't want to set it to "allow-from", I want to get rid of this all together if possible. I've located the config files for Thin, but there's nothing inside any of the files relating to x-f-o.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using the `rack-protection` middleware? What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @matt - rails 3.2.9 // as far as i'm aware "rack-protection" isn't installed. hadn't heard of it before either. didn't know how to check if it was, but pretty sure it wasn't (server built from ruby rails linode stack script).